# Mk7 2015 golf gti

Tags: vw, golf

Hello i had oil in my coolant but engine lloked fine so i had to change the oil cooler then the coolant color have a white layer on top and when move i can see the water , any ideas ?

also the mechanic  used green water instead of g13 how long i can use it till i need to change it

thanks

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! This is what it looks like now? Was the cooling system flushed after changing out the oil cooler?

Comment: yes a flush was done

Comment: and this is what it looks now , its a white layer on top if i move it the coolant water will appear

Comment: Then you've got one of two things going on ... either the flush wasn't done well enough, or you have another oil leak going into the coolant. I think it is probably the former.

Comment: should i preform another flush?

Comment: That's up to you, but it looks as though the 1st flush wasn't done very well. Flushing it until clean would be my next step.